# Can not change the user owner of a file

Tags: files, permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running [Ubuntu under Windows](https://microsoft.com/store/productId/9N6SVWS3RX71).

I have a file which is owned by a user named `leon`:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 leon leon       0 Jun  8 20:25  linux1.txt
```

but for some reason, I can't change its owner by running (in `/mnt/c/Users/leong/Desktop`):

```
sudo chown leon2 linux1.txt
```

`id leon2` returns:

```
uid=1001(leon2) gid=1001(leon2) groups=1001(leon2)
```

in case this information is somewhat useful.

How can I change the owner?

Comment: does ```sudo chown leon2:leon2 linux1.txt``` work?

Comment: What does "I can't change..." mean? Do you get an error? Does it just not change? Does the file system that this linux1.txt is on even support owners?

Comment: What happens when you run the command?  Do you get an error?  Do you have sudo permissions?  What is the exit status of the command?

Comment: I dont get an error. It simply doesnt change the owner. I also noticed that when i run "groups" leon2 doesnt show up. Could you please explain this to me? The user leon2 has its own group leon2 right?

Comment: we don't know whether it has its own group! It might, depends on how you created it. Could you tell us which file system this is on?

Comment: "leon@MININT-NKOT6LM:/mnt/c/Users/leong/Desktop$" not sure if this is what you are asking for

Comment: not directly, but it answers the question! /mnt/c/: this is almost certainly a Windows file system mount, right?

Comment: Yes. When I run "getent group" leon2 shows up. But when i run "groups" it doesnt. Why's that?

Comment: What are the permissions on the directory containing the file?

Comment: drwxrwxrwx 1 leon leon    4096 Jun  8 20:25  Desktop

Comment: From the looks of things you would have to re-mount the file system. Update Q with `grep '/mnt/c/' /etc/mtab` and likely some wise mount gurus can guide you on the path. Also, if possible, update with information on if you only want to change ownership for one file or all (on `/mnt/c`). If it should persist between re-mounts etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So heres how to solve this issue:

edit or create /etc/wsl.conf:

[automount]
options = "metadata"

then restart ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

The windows file system you're using simply has no notion of "owner".

You can't set that property, since that property has no place to be stored.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I'm sorry, but where does this indicate it's ntfs-3g?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov but I'm not claiming he's doing that? I'm just saying the filesystem is in a state of not having a notion of "owner".

Comment: You are **literally** the only one bringing a specific file system driver into this; I haven't mentioned ntfs-3g so far. For all we know this could be mingw/Msys shell, or WSL, or...

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov you're wrong in that OP hasn't told us what this system is – is it WSL? Then that's a linux kernel, but there very much *is* a different method of mounting NTFS. Is it Mingw/msys? Then there's very much another way. I've not seen anything being automatically mounted under /mnt/, either, so there's very strong suggestions this is *not* what you think, a freestanding linux system trying to work on NTFS.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9N6SVWS3RX71 is what im using. If there arent any properties for owner and group owner, then why does it say there were properties when i run "ls -l"?

Comment: ah, so this is indeed WSL. So, this whole Linux runs as a process under your Windows user; that's why by default the idea that you can change the ownership of files *outside* that VM's own reach isn't implemented. But, Linux has no choice: it has to assume a file is a file with all the properties a file has, i.e. an owner.